# Is it possible to use cudaMemcpy with src and dest as different types?

Tags: memory, cuda

I'm using a Tesla, and for the first time, I'm running low on CPU memory instead of GPU memory! Hence, I thought I could cut the size of my host memory by switching all integers to short (all my values are below 255).

However, I want my device memory to use integers, since the memory access is faster. So is there a way to copy my host memory (in short) to my device global memory (in int)? I guess this won't work:

```
short *buf_h = new short[100];
int *buf_d = NULL;

cudaMalloc((void **)&buf_d, 100*sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpy( buf_d, buf_h, 100*sizeof(short), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a way to do what you are asking directly. The CUDA API doesn't support "smart copying" with padding or alignment, or "deep copying" of nested pointers, or anything like that. Memory transfers require linear host and device memory, and alignment must be the same between source and destination memory.

Having said that, one approach to circumvent this restriction would be to copy the host `short` data to an allocation of `short2` on the device. Your device code can retrieve a `short2` containing two packed shorts, extract the value it needs and then cast the value to `int`. This will give the code 32 bit memory transactions per thread, allowing for memory coalescing, and (if you are using Fermi GPUs) good L1 cache hit rates, because adjacent threads within a block would be reading the same 32 bit word. On non Fermi GPUs, you could probably use a shared memory scheme to efficiently retrieve all the values for a block using coalesced reads.

Comment: If I understand the questioner correctly, they are asking if memcpy can promote short->int during the memcpy, and the answer is No.

A CUDA kernel that used mapped pinned memory to do such a copy would probably saturate PCI Express, though. i.e. it'd run as fast as cudaMemcpy().